# CORS policy error with vuejs in frontend and with php in the backend?

Tags: php, vue.js, apache, symfony, cors

do you know what can cause the cors problem? When I worked on the project locally, there wasn't any CORS error. Now when I deployed it live, I have the CORS error at fetching the data. If I understand it correctly, this is because the frontend app ist on example: https://myapp.com, and the backend is on https://myapp-backend.com. Also the problem comes from the backend side if I'm correct.

The error messages are: `Access to fetch at 'https://example-backend.com/pimcore-graphql-webservices/users?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from origin 'frontend.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status`

I tried some things what I found here stackowerflow's posts. In the .htaccess file I added these lines:

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
</IfModule>
```

in the vite confing I added these lines:

```
cors:{
            "origin": "*",
            "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
            "preflightContinue": false,
            "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
        }
```

I found some extensions for chorme, but they also didn't work.

What else can I try to solve this CORS error?

Comment: What CORS problem? There are dozens of different CORS related problems. We don't know which one you are experiencing. Quote the actual error message.

Comment: edit your post and add some information bro 

and verify your api url ( add "/" in the end) it's famous problem

Comment: `the CORS error`...there are lots of CORS errors. [edit] your post with the specific error you're getting, in full. And in the meantime please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS so you definitely understand fully how CORS works (although it sounds like you have got the basic idea). Thanks.

Comment: @Quentin Access to fetch at 'https://example-backend.com/pimcore-graphql-webservices/users?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from origin 'https://frontend.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: @tg22a — OK. So have you done the basic research and debugging? Have you learned what a preflight is? Have you looked at the response you get for it to find out what the status is ("not OK" eliminates one possibility, but there are many) and if the response body includes any additional information? Have you then looked at the code generating that response so you can change it and respond with an OK status?